# Count maximum number of overlapping date ranges in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I am creating a vehicle rental application. I was trying find overlapping booking in given dates. I come across a similar question [Count maximum number of overlapping date ranges in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60601150/count-maximum-number-of-overlapping-date-ranges-in-mysql) but this only answered for MySQL 8.0.

I modified above question for my problem.
I need solution for **MySQL 5.6** without window function.

```
create table if not exists BOOKING
(
    start datetime null,
    end datetime null,
    vehicle_id varchar(255),
    id int auto_increment
        primary key
);

INSERT INTO BOOKING (start, end, vehicle_id)
VALUES
('2020-02-06 10:33:55', '2020-02-07 10:34:41', 111),
('2020-02-08 10:33:14', '2020-02-10 10:33:57', 111),
('2020-02-06 10:32:55', '2020-02-07 10:33:32', 222),
('2020-08-06 10:33:03', '2020-02-11 10:33:12', 111),
('2020-02-12 10:31:38', '2020-02-15 10:32:41', 111),
('2020-02-09 09:48:44', '2020-02-10 09:50:37', 222);
```

Suppose If I give start as 2020-02-05 and end as  2020-02-11, this should return 2, as maximum usage of vehicle 111, is 2 from 2020-02-06 to 2020-02-10

```
5  6  7  8  9  10  11 
   <-->  <------>
   <---------------->     (Vehicle Id 111, ANSWER should be 2)

for vehicle id 222, (For same query)
5  6  7  8  9  10  11 
   <-->     <--->         (Vehicle Id 222, ANSWER should be 1)
```

So overall output I am expecting for input start(2020-02-05) and end(2020-02-11)

```
+---------+-------+
| vehicle | usage |
+---------+-------+
| 111     | 2     |
| 222     | 1     |
+---------+-------+
```

I need solution which covers followings

- on passing start_date and end_date my query will return data only for that range
- If no data found should return `vehicle_id 0`

Comment: "I modified above question for my problem", you meant to say "I copied the create table and insert statements from this link to here...."  But what did you really try yourself to solve this problem in MySQL 5.6 ?

Comment: I mean I refereed same question for my problem. I tried but answer were given for MySQL8.0 which I am not using. I don't have idea how to count these overlapping things

Comment: Ok, then you should read [ask], and this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of overlaps occurs when a rental starts (although it might persist for a period of time, this is all you care about).

You can calculate this for each start using:

```
SELECT b.vehicle_id, b.start, COUNT(*)
FROM booking b JOIN
     booking b2
     ON b2.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id AND
        b2.start <= b.start AND
        b2.end > b.start
WHERE b.start <= $end and b.end >= $start
GROUP BY b.vehicle_id, b.start;
```

Then for the maximum:

```
SELECT vehicle_id, MAX(overlaps)
FROM (SELECT b.vehicle_id, b.start, COUNT(*) as overlaps
      FROM booking b JOIN
           booking b2
           ON b2.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id AND
              b2.start <= b.start AND b2.end > b.start
      GROUP BY b.vehicle_id, b.start
     ) b
GROUP BY vehicle_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=52fdab923d28ffcdcf7a6bbd2cc63e57) is a db<>fiddle.

Performance on this type of query is never going to be as good as using window functions.  However, an index on `(vehicle_id, start, end)` would help.

Comment: Where to put my input parameters (Which will be supplied by application) start_date & return_date of range/period for which I want to query this. As I also mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Jai . . . I added the `where` clause in the first query.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT vehicle_id vehicle, MAX(cnt) `usage`
FROM ( SELECT booking.vehicle_id, timepoints.dt, COUNT(*) cnt
       FROM booking
       JOIN ( SELECT start dt FROM booking
              UNION ALL
              SELECT `end` FROM booking ) timepoints ON timepoints.dt BETWEEN booking.start AND booking.`end`
       GROUP BY booking.vehicle_id, timepoints.dt ) subquery
GROUP BY vehicle_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=05205bae466ae949d3f6fde33b38996d)

PS. Misprint in 4th row is corrected.

Comment: I am little confuse, where should I pass my input for start date and end date of the range for which I want data

Comment: @Jai Depends on the task. If the table range must be within than in both subqueries, else in the most inner one. Anycase the algo is described in the fiddle - update according step(s) in it.

Comment: @Akina . .  . Although this produces the correct answer, it is much more performance-intensive than necessary.